# Android: Arraylist collection sort

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

In My array list I have name and number, but its not alphabetical. I am using set adapter method for setting all name and number.

I am confused hot to use **collection Sort** in array list for both name and number

Can any please give me an idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Implement Comparable interface to your Contact model like

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>
```

override compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(Fruit Contact )
```

sort by any field you want

finally use

```
Arrays.sort(Contacts);
```

it will sort accordingly

please follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

`isAsc` is boolean variable used to check. You want to sort in ascending order or descending order.

`arraySquads` is my `ArrayList` of `TeamModal` type modal class.

```
 if (isAsc) {
                Collections.sort(arraySquads, new Comparator<TeamModal>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(TeamModal emp1, TeamModal emp2) {
                        String playerName1=emp1.getNick_name());
                        String playerName2=emp2.getNick_name());
                        return playerName1.compareToIgnoreCase(
                                playerName2);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Collections.sort(arraySquads, new Comparator<TeamModal>(){
                    public int compare(TeamModal emp1, TeamModal emp2) {
                        String playerName1=emp1.getNick_name();
                        String playerName2=emp2.getNick_name();
                        return  playerName2.compareToIgnoreCase(playerName1);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
Person p = new Person("Bruce", "Willis");
Person p1  = new Person("Tom", "Hanks");
Person p2 = new Person("Nicolas","Cage");
Person p3 = new Person("John","Travolta");

ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(p);
list.add(p1);
list.add(p2);
list.add(p3);

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator(){

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Person p1 = (Person) o1;
        Person p2 = (Person) o2;
       return p1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getFirstName());
    }

});
```

This will sort the array list in alphabetically. and the list you got is alphabetically arranged